# C++ equivalent to C99 Compound Literals

Tags: c++, serialization, c++20

I'm new to modern C++. I'm writing a serializer and need to write a single byte (a delimiter) out. In C99 I would use a compound literal to hold the value, something like this:

```
enum {
   TAG_DELIMITER,
   // ...
   TAG_MAX
};

void write_buf(out_buf *dest, char *src, size_t n);

void encode(out_buf *buf, user_data *d) {
   // ... Write out user data
   write_buf(buf, &(char){TAG_DELIMITER}, sizeof(char));
}
```

In C++ the setup is similar:

```
class UserData {
public:
  // ... Some data

  void encode(std::ostream &buf) {
    // ... Write out user data
    char tmp = TAG_DELIMITER;
    buf.write(&tmp, sizeof(tmp));
  }
}
```

Declaring a `tmp` variable feels clumsy. This isn't a big deal, and I could just use extensions to enable compound literals if I really cared. But is there a "C++-ish" way of doing this I'm missing? Targeting C++20 on GCC 10.1

EDIT: To clarify, the values from the enum are used all over the code base so I'm not going to make it into a bunch of constexprs inside a class. In any case that's just moving my `tmp` variable into a static class member, which really isn't any better.

This question perhaps would have been better stated, "Is there a way to declare and get the address of an anonymous variable in C++?" To which I think the answer is No.

In any case, the comments were right that what I really want here is just `ostream.put(TAG_DELIMITER)` which neatly side steps the whole question.

Comment: constexpr inline char TAG_DELIMITER = 'a';

Comment: @Vasilij [You can't get the address of a constexpr](https://godbolt.org/z/7hTY6e) and I'm not trying to use globals here anyway.

Comment: @nickelpro it works for me, using your link, you just need to make sure you put const in the right places! https://godbolt.org/z/s8b13x

Comment: Well, I tried this: https://godbolt.org/z/3MsoW6 and it worked with std::ostream. But I agree globals are bad, but I just followed the C example with enum.

Comment: You haven't said what `buf` is in the C++ code.   But, assuming it is a `std::basic_ostream` (or a specialisation like `std::ostream` or a derived class like `std::ofstream`) you can simply do `buf.put((char)TAG_DELIMITER)` to output a single character.

Comment: Just for clarification - one can get the address of a constexpr: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37789026/how-to-define-a-pointer-pointing-to-a-constexpr-variable

Comment: @Vasilij Yep, I was totally wrong, my little test was malformed.

Comment: @nickelpro, not a problem, you made me lookup and refresh this thing, which I am happy of))) Good question, btw, I enjoyed the discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Youn can use `constexpr`:

```
class UserData {
public:
    constexpr static char TAG_DELIMITER = 'a';
  // ... Some data

  void encode(std::ostream &buf) {
    // ... Write out user data
    const char * tmp = &TAG_DELIMITER;
    buf.write(tmp, sizeof(char));
  }
};
```

However, when you try to take its address, then you need to use `const char *`.

Comment: Or just `constexpr static char TAG_DELIMITER[] = {'a'};` and no need for `tmp`. Or, if all TAG_* are single characters, just `buf.put(TAG_DELIMITER)`.

Comment: You also could use `sizeof(*tmp)` if you're sneaky.